# SEO-wise, can I rewrite image links live via jQuery?

Tags: jquery, seo

I am designing a rather complex homepage of a website. The page will contain a slider with some images, the path of which has to be corrected on `document.ready`. After the path can be determined, I plan to change it in the image tags via jQuery. Until now, these images have had a valid path, but one that will be changed to another valid path.

So, the process is as follows:

1. Page loads with some images in the slider (valid URLs pointing to some images)
2. jQuery executes and changes the URLs of the images

Is this OK from a SEO perspective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally Google today Execute JavaScript, there are evidence of so http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157

So if you set the script at document load it's totally fine,

What I can recommend to you is to use some frequently used library such as :
https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes

In addition to SEO friendly you will get an Mobile friendly version of you images when you specify the required tags so you will benefit from mobile friendly factor:
https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/6196932?hl=en

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the insight.